# I want conditional Login navigation without MAIN fragment or button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Android Jetpack Navigation Component, Live Data, and Firebase.
I want a the workflow to be like when the user OPENS the app, then based on the login/logout status navigate to Login/Profile fragment WITHOUT ANY MAIN FRAGMENT OR A BUTTON (please).
There is no main fragment in my app. User launches the app and navigate directly to the fragment(Login/Profile) according to the login status.
I have seen numerous stack overflow questions but they all have the MAIN fragment and a button to decide the navigation thereafter.

Please tell me how to do this. Please!

I am using JAVA.
[Please see the image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mqB8.jpg)

Comment: What screen do you launch after you login? That's your main screen. The [Conditional Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) talks specifically about how you should be approaching login. Have you read those docs? Please include your code.

Comment: You need some kind of splash page, but not as an activity, rather as a fragment, right?

Comment: @ianhanniballake First I want to show the user the Sign Up/Sign In fragment. After Sign Up/Sign In the user moves to Profile(fragment)... I have read the docs. It does say that in conditional navigation , in My case the start (home) destination of the navGraph should be the Profile Fragment(in my case) and only if the user is not logged in then show the SignUp/Sign In fragment... but in the examples given there is a button where the user navigates to. I DONOT WANT A fragment with a BUTTON... I want the user to open the app and directly navigate according to login status-NO BUTTON ON STARTUP

Comment: @AlexMamo I want a sign up/sign in fragment to show based on the users' login status(if yes directly navigate to Profile Fragment or if not logged in then navigate to Sign Up/SignIn fragment).... Without any button ... I have also added an image ... Please please see that image ... I have explained in that Image in detail what functionality I want.

Comment: The Conditional Navigation docs do not have any 'button on startup' - they explain how to automatically redirect the user to the login page if you are not logged in. Please reread the documentation and actually try it: it provides exactly the user experience you are looking for.

Comment: In the docs, there is a "View Profile" button that exists in the main Fragment. On click, the user is redirected to the Profile/Sign-in Fragment according to the authentication state. So you don't want that button and the main Fragment, right? But how would you like to achieve that since you need a starting point?

Comment: @AlexMamo... Hello sir. Your are a genius ! actually I have read several of your Stack answers. I want a behavior like when you open the Fb app there is no button to decide your navigation. If already logged in then navigate to Profile Fragment or else navigate to the Sign Up/Login Fragment . I want similar behavior.  also like a splash screen ??? how to do that ? a fragment or an activity when using navigation Component since it works with One Activity ONLY. Please tell sir ! thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes ! you have understood my question ... Ok. as per your reply I will look into the official docs again and revert back to you ..... thanks again !

Comment: @ianhanniballake No sir ! I think there is some misunderstanding here. In the official docs they have a MAIN FRAGMENT AND BUTTON that decides whether to navigate the user to Profile Fragment or any other. I do not want this. I want a behavior like in FB app when we open the app, If ALREADY LOGGED In then app directly takes us to the Profile (or Home Feed) fragment. and if the user is not logged in then navigate to the Sign up /login fragment. I want this behavior in my app. I do not want any button or MAIN FRAGMENT. please do reply .. thank you!

Comment: No, that's not what the docs say at all. You'll note there is no code for MainFragment, no 'button that decides whether to navigate the user to Profile Fragment or any other'. The docs point by point tell you how to make your ProfileFragment require a login and automatically redirect the user to login. That is exactly your case. Just forget about the MainFragment at all, it isn't relevant to how you make a destination require login.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i also have one question .. like when I am using navComponent, then how to show the splash? should I do it through a new Activity (I don't think so as navComponent supports only one Activity) or shall I do with a fragment .... Please tell !

Comment: @SabirAli I think you might be interested in reading this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8). There is no "View Profile" button that exists in the main Fragment, no splash activity, and no fragment. Is this what you want?